# Display number N , N times in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need your help.

I have a number '10' in A3 cell of MS Excel. Now, i want to select the number '10' and display 'hello' 10 times in the excel.

Similarly, if i have any number N( not very large number), how can i display the some text "N" times.

Please help. I want to display "hello" in N different cells.

Thanks,
JT

Comment: Do you want to display it N times in one cell or one time in N cells? Please [edit] your question post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Pick some cell and enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$A$3,"","hello")
```

Then copy down

[image]

If you change the value in **A3,** the number of *Hello* s will chnage.

Comment: "Hello" is posted only once. if i have 5 in A3, i want hello to be printed 5 times in different cells..

Comment: Make sure Calculation mode is set to **Automatic**

Comment: Make sure the **A3** contents is **numeric** and not **Text**

Comment: @jay- yes... i want it to be printed 5 times.. how can i do that..??

Comment: In my post I said to enter the formula in some cell and then copy that cell downwards.  In my picture, I entered the formula in cell **C3** then I copied cell **C3** to the cells below it.  Please do the same.